# How to add multiple background images with linear-gradients?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 background images one is logo and banner image. I need to apply linear-gradient to 2nd image so that i can blur it to see the above text clearly but the banner image is not displaying properly.

Below is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
.banner{
 background-image: url('https://diylogodesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Pizza-Hut-Logo-PNG-Transparent-Background.png'), linear-gradient(rgba(84, 84, 84,0.7), rgba(84, 84, 84,0.7)), url('https://albicja.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/berlin.jpg');
    background-size: cover, cover;
    background-position: left top, center;
    color: white;
    padding: 70px 0;
    background-size: 80px auto, auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container {
 width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.letterSpacing {
 letter-spacing: 12px;
}

@media(max-width: 992px) {
 .container {
  width: 600px;
 }
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
 .container {
  width: 500px;
 }
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
 .container {
  width: 400px;
 }
}
</style>

<div class="banner">
 <div class="container">
     <h2 class="letterSpacing">Standard Lorem Ipsum passage</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <h3>Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC</h3>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    
    <h3>Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC</h3>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please correct me where am wrong !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am correct!..

```
 .banner{
    background-image: url('https://diylogodesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Pizza-Hut-Logo-PNG-Transparent-Background.png'), linear-gradient(rgba(84, 84, 84,0.7), rgba(84, 84, 84,0.7)), url('https://albicja.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/berlin.jpg');
    background-size: cover, cover;
    background-position: left top, center;
    color: white;
    padding: 70px 0;
    background-size: 80px auto, auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

your Banner image appears smaller and it is because you declared background-size twice and in second time you declared it to take **80px**. if you remove that the image will cover entire space.

you can play with it here [codepen link to your code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jQjXPy)

for easy reference pasting the code here.

```
    <style>
.banner{
    background: url('https://diylogodesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Pizza-Hut-Logo-PNG-Transparent-Background.png'), linear-gradient(rgba(84, 84, 84,0.89), rgba(84, 84, 84,0.89)), url('https://albicja.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/berlin.jpg');
    background-size: 10%, cover, cover ;
    background-position: center, center, center;
    color: white;
    padding: 70px 0;
/*     background-size: 80px auto, auto; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.letterSpacing {
    letter-spacing: 12px;
}

@media(max-width: 992px) {
    .container {
        width: 600px;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        width: 500px;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
    .container {
        width: 400px;
    }
}
</style>
<div class="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="letterSpacing">Standard Lorem Ipsum passage</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <h3>Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC</h3>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>

    <h3>Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC</h3>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please explain why background-size and background-position has 3 values

Comment: background  1. image 2. gradient 3. image(logo) so we are trying to tell it to handle them precisely how we want them to be. in each case. in background-position if you change the value from center, center, center to 4em center, center, center you will see that the logo is placed at left center.

Comment: background-size the value is 10%, cover, cover that means the logo should take around within 300px and other backgrounds image and gradient 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. Furthermore, you shouldn't use comma when separating the background position values. just like you dont say `margin:0px,0px,0px,0px;` you don't say `background-position: left top, center;`

```
.banner {
   background:  url('https://albicja.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/berlin.jpg'), linear-gradient(rgba(84,84,84,0.9) 40%, rgba(84,84,84,0.8) 80%), url('https://albicja.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/berlin.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position: left top; /* specify 2 or 4 sides either (up/down, left/right) or (up, left, bottom, right)*/
   color: white;
   padding: 70px 0px;
}
```